# Appcompat is not able to compile due to some version error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

below is my gradle file
ANdroid studio is displaying this message

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.0.2, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.t.t"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ANd when i am running the app, app crashes on run time displaying the following error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.tapesh.tapu_chat-2/base.apk)

Comment: what is the build tool version?

Comment: actually I have removed the buildtoolsversion, as I had updated my android studio to 3.0.1 , so there is no requirement as android studio suggested me

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using build tool version 26.0.2 and you are using some support dependencies. Try this.

For example:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

}
```

and

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'

}
```

Comment: I had made the change.. then also its not working

Comment: please paste your updated gradle after this change.

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tapesh.tapu_chat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
        //implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.+'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

Comment: did u tried adding 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2' and 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2' in ur gradle?

Answer (score 0):

`getFont()` will work from Android 'O'(`26.0.0-beta1`) version

So update your build tool version to: `"27.0.2"`

**Example**: build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Updated Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html)

Comment: I had made the changes but still its not working

Comment: if you have multiple buld.gradle...make sure to update version in all of them...and clean build the project